# Bash script which can be executed after password is supplied

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I need to get a hold of web-server logs by regular users who have `/bin/bash` as their shell enabled. Logs are stored in a directory which has `drwx------` permissions and is owned by `root:root` so obviously they can't access any files in it (*and yes, I can't really change this permissions setup*).

The system(s) is Debian Linux. So I'm looking for some wrapper script, it might not be `bash` exactly, which, in my vision, will do the following:

- you pass one argument to it - a sitename - i.e. `site.com`;
- it `grep`s all the lines containing this `site.com`;
- stores the result to user home dir.

This part is easy, the real problem arises when you want to bypass restrictions yet to stay (at least somewhat) *safe*. So:

- script **must only** be started after password is provided for it to be run;
- in case of bash scripts they are run with permissions of the user account who ran it - so my guess is it should have `su -m root -c 'grep ...'` in it, but I found no way how to pass password to the prompt inside the script so far (`sudo` is not exactly suitable unfortunately);
- if there is a way to pass password to `su` from inside the script then of course script itself must have permissions `751` and owner of `root:root` - so that the end user who runs the script (or anyone else) won't be able to see the script's content.

I'm open to suggestions how this should be done or if it's should be done at all (at least this way) :) Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a good case for `sudo`.

Comment: @pgl problem is, there are different servers with different users and the whole idea spins around this script being somewhat unified and reusable. Adding another user to sudo is both dangerous and tedious to me :/

Comment: Well, get it right and you can just copy configuration around rather than copy scripts around. Generally `sudo` is way safer than trying to roll-your-own security.

Comment: If you don't need real-time access to your log, maybe a `cron` job on the server might be the way to go? It could extract at regular intervals the required data and store them on a location accessible to you.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux actually cron might be the way to go. it could work like: 1) have a $file in /tmp/ where are site name(s) which need to be grep'ed - and they appear there by executing a script which needs password to be executed; 2) cron job runs every N minutes and does all the grepping using site names from $file. 3) when grepping is done - $file is emptied. Sounds right? :)

Comment: if not sudo, check out the su pam module, for different ways of authenticating su

Comment: Either you store the password in the script itself (pointless) or you need some support on each host on which the script will run (which is exactly what `sudo` provides).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what I understand of your needs, I summarize here the various options that come to my mind. In no particular order:

- Use `sudo` together with a policy file (`/etc/sudoers` -- edit with
  `visudo`) to restrict the commands available to the user
- Use a `cron` job (more or less *smart*) to collect data on the server at regular
  intervals and store them at a location accessible to you (or *mail* them to you...)
- If you have administrative access to the server, you might create a special user with 
  the "log-grepping" tool as connection shell (`/etc/passwd`)
- If you have ssh access to your server, you may also use the
  `authorized_keys` file on the server to [restrict remote command over ssh](http://www.wallix.org/2011/10/18/restricting-remote-commands-over-ssh/)

Those are only general directions. Read about them. Try them. And if you're struggled, don't hesitate to post an other question!

As a last word, as it has already been stated in a comment, please refrain yourself to develop your own "security restriction system". `sudo`, `ssh`, `pam` (and probably others ... `selinux`?) have been specifically crafted for that purpose...